# ReactJS tag rasa nlu entities text highlighting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rasa-nlu

I'm developing a simple react app to show rasa HTTP api results data, and I want to tag the entities in a sentence. My code works good for 1 word entity but breaks with 2 words (only the first word is highlighted)

This is what I'm doing

```
  const [colors, setColors] = useState([
    "salmon",
    "primary",
    "purple",
    "orange"
  ]);

  const tagSentence = () => {
    let sentence = props.data.text;
    const entities = props.data.entities;

    entities.map((e, eIndex) => {
      sentence = sentence.replace(e.value, `<${eIndex}>${e.value}`);
    });
    return sentence.split(" ");
  };


          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
            {props.data.entities.map(t => {
              if (t.value.includes("<")) {
                return (
                  <Chip
                    key={t.value}
                    label={t.slice(3, t.length)}
                    color="primary"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: colors[t.slice(1, 2)] }}
                  />
                );
              } else {
                return ` ${t} `;
              }
            })}
          </Typography>
```

Entities object has the index of start and end of the words , but I cant figure out how to use it.

Example sentence :

Peter is my best friend

```
{
"text" : "peter is my best friend"
"entities" : [{"entity": "PERSON", "value": "peter", "start": 1, "end": 5...}]
}
```

EDIT:

Ended with this, now looking how to make whole word includes in JS

```
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
            {props.data.text.split(" ").map((s, sIndex) => {
              return props.data.entities.map((e, eIndex) => {
                if (e.value.includes(s)) {
                  return (
                    <Chip
                      key={s}
                      label={s}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: colors[sIndex] }}
                      color="primary"
                    />
                  );
                } else {
                  return ` ${s} `;
                }
              });
            })}
          </Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace to easily replace  strings with components, worked like a charm.

```
  const tagSentence = () => {
    let sentence = props.data.text;
    props.data.entities.forEach((e, eIndex) => {
      sentence = reactStringReplace(sentence, e.value, (match, i) => (
        <Chip
          key={i}
          label={match}
          style={{ backgroundColor: colors[eIndex] }}
          color="primary"
        />
      ));
    });
    return sentence;
  };
```